# How can I detach a specific relationship to a node then "move" it to another node in a graph database?

Tags: performance, neo4j, graph, query-performance

I'm trying to make a game using the neo4j graph database as an experiment. Some nodes are `Users` and some nodes are `Rooms`. `Rooms` have a `CONTAINS` relationship to `Users` so the database has a lot of this: `(someroom)-[CONTAINS]->(someuser)`

When a `User` leaves a `Room` and enters another in the game, the `CONTAINS` relationship needs to reflect that by detaching from the `Room` and reattaching to a different `Room`. Is there a way to do this without deleting and recreating that relationship? Like some sort of advanced, more efficient `SET` command that changes the origin of the relationship?